# Clojure + Korma - SUM aggregation query with IF condition

Tags: mysql, clojure, korma

How does sum-if work in Korma?

Here is the sample query

```
SELECT SUM(if(items.quantities > 1, 1, 0)) AS multiples FROM items;
```

I got this to work with raw-exec provided by Korma. But, I am interested in knowing how to write this in the Korma syntax.

I have tried looking at http://sqlkorma.com/docs#select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF` is a vendor specific function, so I doubt it will be supported.

You might have better luck transforming your query into something vendor neutral and using that instead.

This query:

```
SELECT SUM(if(items.quantities > 1, 1, 0)) AS multiples FROM items;
```

is equivalent to the following one:

```
SELECT count(*) AS multiples FROM items WHERE quantities > 1;
```

which translates to the following korma expression:

```
(select items 
     (aggregate (count  :*) :multiples) 
     (where {:quantities [> 1]}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this one:

```
(select items
        (fields (raw "SUM(if(items.quantities > 1, 1, 0)) AS multiples"))
```